# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. in scipy.optimize.minimize + curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, valueerror, minimize

I am a newbie at Python and I was writing a code to compute, then fit, magnetization data.

Firstly, I am writing the function for the energy to be minimized with respect to the parameter "theta".

```py
def E_uniaxial(H, phi, theta, Keff, Ms):

    e = Keff*(np.cos(theta))**2 - ((4*np.pi)**2*mu0)*Ms*H*np.cos(theta - phi)
    return e
```

Then, as the magnetization depends strongly on the previous equilibriuum position of the system, I write a function for the "next equilibriuum position", the parameter H is the one supposed to change between the previous and the new equilibriuum position.

```py
def next_theta(Ms, phi, Keff, H, lasttheta, fctE):

    E = lambda x : fctE(H, phi, x, Keff, Ms)[0]
    result = scipy.optimize.minimize(E, lasttheta)
    return result.x
```

After this, I write a function that computes a whole hysteresis cycle. Given a starting point that is known, the function increases H and computes all the equilibriuum positions that depends on the previous one (then H is decreased and the same process is performed).

```py
def cycle_theta(Ms, desfield, Keff, Hmax, theta_init_1, theta_init_2, fctE):

    #aller
    H1 = np.linspace(-Hmax, Hmax, 2000)
    sol1 = np.zeros(np.shape(H1))
    sol1[0] = theta_init_1
    for i in range(len(H1)-1):
        sol1[i+1] = next_theta(Ms, desfield, Keff, H1[i+1], sol1[i], fctE)

    #retour
    H2 = np.linspace(Hmax, -Hmax, 2000)
    sol2 = np.zeros(np.shape(H2))
    sol2[0] = theta_init_2
    for i in range(len(H2) -1):
        sol2[i+1] = next_theta(Ms, desfield, Keff, H2[i+1], sol2[i], fctE)

    return H1, sol1, np.flip(sol2)
```

Then, I have to fit data in order to find the Ms and Keff parameters. I defined this function :

```py
def test_fit(H, Ms, Keff):

    a = cycle_theta(Ms, 1., Keff, 20, np.pi, 0., E_uniaxial)[1]
    idx = 0

    if isinstance(H, float):
        idx = find_nearest(a, H)
        print('float')
        return np.sin(a[idx])
    if isinstance(H, np.ndarray):
        c = np.zeros(np.shape(H))
        for i in range(len(H)):
            idx = find_nearest(a, H[i])
            c[i] = a[idx]
            print('array')
            return np.sin(c)
```

The condition on the type seemed to be required for the function to work with curve_fit.
I finally call `popt = curve_fit(test_fit, b, sig)` where "b" and "sig" are my experimental data.

But I got this error several times coming from the `scipy.optimize.minimize`, not the curve_fit:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I read that this message can come from the fact my energy function E_unixial returns an array and not a scalar, but actually it's a quite regular function : if you input a scalar, you get a scalar and if you input an array, you get an array.
So I really don't understand, am I not supposed to use scipy.optimize.minimize and scipy.minimize.curve_fit one into the other ?

Thank you **a lot** for your help !!

Comment: From `scipy.optimize.minimize` docs: Minimization of scalar function of one or more variables. So my guess is you should modify your function to return a float. This ValueError usually comes when you try to put a sequence of numbers into a single element slot in a numpy array.

Comment: Excuse me, what function needs to return a float please ?